# Next seo test with react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, meta-tags, react-testing-library

I am trying to test my SEO component which looks like this:

```
export const Seo: React.FC<Props> = ({ seo, title, excerpt, heroImage }) => {
  const description = seo?.description || excerpt
  const pageTitle = seo?.title || title

  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <NextSeo // https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-seo
      canonical={seo?.canonical}
      nofollow={seo?.nofollow}
      noindex={seo?.noindex}
      title={pageTitle}
      description={description}
      openGraph={{
        title,
        description,
        type: "article",
...
```

and my test is like so:

```
describe("Seo", () => {
  it("should render the meta tags", async () => {
    const props = {
      title: "title page",
      excerpt: "string",
      seo: {
        title: "seo title",
        description: "meta description",
      },
      heroImage: {
        src: "url",
        alt: "alt text",
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
      },
    }

    function getMeta(metaName: string) {
      const metas = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")
      for (let i = 0; i < metas.length; i += 1) {
        if (metas[i].getAttribute("name") === metaName) {
          return metas[i].getAttribute("content")
        }
      }
      return ""
    }

    render(<Seo {...props} />)

    await waitFor(() => expect(getMeta("title")).toEqual("title page"))
  })
})
```

however the test is failing: (it looks like the head element is empty)

[image]

Comment: i think problem here, you need show in console this `document.getElementsByTagName("meta")`

Comment: That's right it's actually empty `HTMLCollection {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same issue, but I found [this answer on GitHub](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11060#discussioncomment-33628).

So basically you need to mock `next/head`, pass `document.head` to the container property of `render`'s options and finally access the `document`.

Your test would end up like this:

```
jest.mock('next/head', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: ({ children }: { children: Array<React.ReactElement> }) => {
      return <>{children}</>;
    },
  };
});

describe("Seo", () => {
  it("should render the meta tags", () => {
    const props = {
      title: "title page",
      excerpt: "string",
      seo: {
        title: "seo title",
        description: "meta description",
      },
      heroImage: {
        src: "url",
        alt: "alt text",
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
      },
    }

    render(<Seo {...props} />, { container: document.head })

    expect(document.title).toBe("title page")
  })
})
```

In my case I didn't test it with that `getMeta` function but I believe it would work too.

Answer (score -1):

in JS

```
jest.mock('next/head', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: ({ children }) => {
      return children;
    }
  };
});
```